# PHP with HTML echo in echo

Tags: php, html

For some reason after my table displays the following extra text: echo;"

I've played with the code a lot but get the same result.

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{

    echo "<table>";
    echo(
        "<tr>"
        ."<th>"
        ."Online Users"
        .$num_rows
               ."</th>"
               ."<th>"
        ."Offline Users"
               ."</th>"
                ."</tr>"
    );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo(
            "<tr>"
            ."<td>"
            .row['name']
            ."</td>"
            ."</tr>"
            );

    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "an error has occurred";
}
```

Comment: I don't think echo (); is right syntax... It's rather echo "hhsjsjdn";

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your server is not parsing the PHP at all; it's returning it to the browser as if it were HTML. You need to do three things:

1. Make sure you have `<?php` before the code in your question.
2. Make sure your file's name ends in `.php`.
3. Make sure your server has PHP installed and knows to interpret `.php` files as PHP, not as HTML.

Many variations of this question have been asked here before, though I couldn't find an exact duplicate. It's not clear from your question which of the above 3 steps is causing your problem.